# Failed to read CA certs(GetCertificateChain does not return full chain)

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, keychain, pkcs#12

I am using the method below to read certificates.

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    ks.load(in, password);
    String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    ...
```

This method is very functional, however I came across a problem in a certificate that does not load the full string of the certificate.

**For example1:**
[When reading certificate 1 the statement below returns 4 strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea3oZ.png)

**For example2:**
[When reading certificate 2 the statement below returns only one string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDawe.png)

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

**EDIT**

Trying to explain better, this certificate is used to connect to a WS. During the communication process WS returns the following rejection Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
The connection to this WS requires the complete certification chain presentation.

As mentioned below the certificate shows the failure in JAVA, but it works perfectly in .NET, correctly displaying the certification chain

Answer (score 0):

According to [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html):

> **Returns:**
>   the certificate chain (ordered with the user's certificate first followed by zero or more certificate authorities), or null if the given alias does not exist or does not contain a certificate chain

This means that either, there are no more certificates in the chain (self-signed certificate) or required chain elements are not included in PKCS#12 message and are not available through other sources.

Comment: I understand your point. However the problem continues because this same certificate works correctly if imported via .NET.
By using an example of .NET the system can load and display all the certificate chains

Comment: .NET and Java are different platforms with different APIs and may produce different results.